# My rat is drooling/has thick spit and it looks like blood. They are also heaving as if they are trying to vomit

Tags: health, rat

I have a senior rat, about three years in age who just started spitting up/drooling blood like substance, though it looks pinkish, and he will occasionally heave as if he is trying to puke. He is also breathing heavily and has his mouth open sometimes.

I know that some of the symptoms mean that he is "choking" and that they will get through it themselves, but I feel like this is a little different than that because no one says Thea the drool substance has a pinkish bloody like look to it.

If it helps, it also seems that my poor boy has been losing weight even though his food intake hasn't changed and we haven't changed the type of food we've been giving him. However, we occasionally give them romaine lettuce and now with the problems the lettuce has been having, could that be what's causing this?

I really need as much help as possible, thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a severe medical problem that cannot be solved over the internet. **Please see a vet as soon as possible!** We are random people trying to help others with questions about keeping or training pets. We are no vets and cannot diagnose your pet. The heaving, choking, vomiting blood and weight loss sounds like a medical emergency that you should get examined as soon as possible, or it might lead to the death of your cat soon.

Comment: How long has this been going on for? It does sound like a medical emergency and you should take your pet to the vet. Let us know how it goes.